# Spark Cassandra Performance Issue

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am a new learner of Spark and Cassandra. I am facing a major performance issue.I am streaming the data from Kafka at every 5 seconds in Spark, then perform analytic on the data in R language using JRI and finally saving the data to Cassandra's respective column family. The time duration(in milliseconds) for saving the data to Cassandra increases very rapidly with the number of input requests [each request is 200KB].

[image: Spark Performance]

Spark code:

```
 sessionData.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<NormalizedData>, Void>() {
    public Void call(JavaRDD<NormalizedData> rdd)     {
System.out.println("step-3 " + System.currentTimeMillis());
javaFunctions(rdd).writerBuilder("keyspace",normalized_data",mapToRow(NormalizedData.class)).saveToCassandra();
System.out.println("step-4 " + System.currentTimeMillis());}}
```

Comment: spark-default.conf:connection.spark.Cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms 3600000 spark.Cassandra.output.batch.size.rows 2                                                 spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes10                                                                                                                           spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes 2m                                                                                                                          spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb 1 mbPlease let me kno

Answer (score 0):

I was able to enhance performance for the same by using Spark and Cassandra on the same server. This delay was because Spark and Cassandra were on different server though in same region on AWS. The network delay was the main cause as it impacted data locality. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [blog](http://www.snappydata.io/blog/snappydata-memsql-cassandra-a-performance-benchmark) for Spark-Cassandra connector tuning. You will get an idea on perf numbers that you can expect. Also You can try out another open source product SnappyData, which is the Spark database, which will give you very high performance in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Cassandra Spark combination to do realtime analytics. The following things are a few best practices:

1. **Data Locality** - Running Cassandra daemon with Worker node in case of Spark standalone or Node Manager in case of Yarn], Mesos worker in case of Mesos
2. **Increase the parallelism** i.e., create more partitions/tasks
3. Use Cassandra Connection Pooling to improve throughput

> In your case, you are using JRI to call R in side Java. This is a bit
>   slowly and performance overhead. So use SparkR to integrate R with Spark instead of JRI directly.